# Next Js - [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]

Tags: typescript, next.js

I use Next Auth to add authentification to my website. But when I try to create customs pages I get this error:

https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error request to https://mdejfrmkwowodmwel/api/auth/providers failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mdejfrmkwowodmwel

```html
{  error: {
    message: 'request to https://mdejfrmkwowodmwel/api/auth/providers failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mdejfrmkwowodmwel',
    stack: 'FetchError: request to https://mdejfrmkwowodmwel/api/auth/providers failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mdejfrmkwowodmwel\n' +
      '    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (E:\\nextjs\\ingenious-city-lms\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\node-fetch\\index.js:1:64142)\n' +
      '    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:375:28)\n' +
      '    at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:470:12)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:470:12)\n' +
      '    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)\n' +
      '    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)',
    name: 'FetchError'
  },
  path: 'providers',
  message: 'request to https://mdejfrmkwowodmwel/api/auth/providers failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mdejfrmkwowodmwel'
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have configured the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable properly with a valid URL.

Comment: It was the issue